# When cd is inserted it will not play 16.04

Tags: rhythmbox, cd-drive

Previously when I inserted a music cd, a cd icon appeared in the sidebar and I could open Rhythmbox to play it. I had some problem with ejecting the cd so tried looking at the shortcuts setting. I don't think I changed anything. But now when I insert the cd, the cd icon does not appear and the drive does not fire up. The eject command still causes the cd to eject. Rhythmbox does not show the cd drive and nor does vlc.
Thanks
Just tried the command eject and got:
~$ eject
eject: unable to eject, last error: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Installed udftools but no change.
Edit: I also notice that the removable media setting changes from Rhythmbox to VLC without me doing anything to it.
Edit: I uninstalled VLC and rebooted and now the cd works fine again. I think VLC was interfering with the settings as I may have configured it to be the default player within VLC when I installed it. So, thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Try rebooting.  If I don't eject the CD using file manager, it seems to get confused.

Comment: I just rebooted and re-inserted the cd. No change. The light on the cd tray flashes but it does not fire up and there is no visible response from ubuntu

Comment: Do any other CDs work?

Comment: I have just rebooted again, with the cd inserted. The drive whirred up but did not do anything. Alt_e displays a box with the eject symbol but does not eject it. The command eject does not eject the tray and seems to hang. I tried pressing the eject button on the tray and nothing seemed to happen and then as I was typing this post, it ejected. Looking at the settings for the keyboard, sound and media, the eject option is set to Alt-E. When I first looked, it was set to "New accelerator...". But if I try this setting, the dialog box will not close. The issue remains the same with a different cd

Comment: Sounds like my surprise today after I fried grub and the Live CD wouldn't boot... have you tried booting with the live CD yet?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the Live CD. If it refers to a bootable cd with Ubuntu I don't have one. But I could try and make a bootable dvd to see if that would mount the device for me. Mmmm.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix It might be easier to test the drive from live media if the OP booted from Live flash:  https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Comment: @ElderGeek The reason for Live CD was just to see how it works when booting-- The CD not working after Ubuntu is running is the gist of the question.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Point taken, however since the problem reported is audio cds not detected, if we boot from live USB media we can test that as well.

Comment: @ElderGeek I was just trying to find out if the CD actually worked. The OP wasn't clear on that. I did add an answer to ensure option to auto-play CD is turned on. We'll have to wait for OP to post back.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes. Saw and corrected that.

Comment: @ElderGeek Yes I just noticed your edit-- Thank you for that. Also thank you for your edit a couple hours ago? on `How to connect a Ubuntu laptop to a Ubuntu laptop` using orange ethernet cross over cable :)

Comment: post results of this, must return true for autoplay on audio cd's `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount`

Answer (score 1):

First off ensure that auto-play settings are turned on. Go to `System Settings`, `Details`, `Removable Media` and this screen appears:

[image: Removable Media]

If your screen looks like this then uncheck the last box and change the default for audio CD's to RythmBox to ensure CD's auto-play.

Comment: That setting, (Never prompt..)  has little to do with audio cd's. Autoplay for them is dependent upon `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount` being set to true (the default

Comment: @doug Do you mind monitoring this thread and posting an answer when the OP responds with additional information? I'd be happy to delete my answer if erroneous.

Comment: No problem, the issue in 16.04 is that the automounting of internal & external volumes also controls removable media like cd's  which it shouldn't. I had a bug on this for quite some time but no one upstream could get the idea they should be separate. So here where I don't want other internal volumes mounted on login but do want audio & dvd's automounted on insertion has lead me to create 2 startup apps. The 1st one disables automount in gsettings, 2nd one, after a few second delay, re-enables automount. Whether this is the op's issue no clue but worth checking if it's been disabled..